# Get id numbers in arrray php with adodb

Tags: php, arrays, select, adodb

I have make this code below but it returns strings, i need only numbers ids.

```
$result7 = "SELECT b.id from boleto b where b.bol_nn = 0 and b.codigo = ".$terceiro." order by b.id";

$sql7 = $db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_NUM);
$sql7 = $db->Execute("$result7");


        foreach ($sql7 as $row) {
                print_r($row);
                        }

/*
Array ( [0] => 538119 ) Array ( [0] => 538120 ) Array ( [0] => 538121 ) Array ( [0] => 538122 ) Array ( [0] => 538123 ) Array ( [0] => 538124 ) Array ( [0] => 538125 ) Array ( [0] => 538126 ) Array ( [0] => 538127 ) Array ( [0] => 538128 ) Array ( [0] => 538129 ) Array ( [0] => 538130 )
*/
```

but i would like an array list with only ids.

```
538119
538120
538121 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or there's a simpler solution :

```
$result7 = "SELECT b.id from boleto b where b.bol_nn = 0 and b.codigo = ".$terceiro." order by b.id";

$sql7 = $db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_NUM);
$sql7 = $db->Execute("$result7");

foreach ($sql7 as $row) {
   $ids[] = $row[0];   // Only this line had changed
}
print_r($ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlresult = $sql7->Fields(0);
```

after retrieving the Recordset via Execute